# numpy multiplication not working

Tags: python, math, numpy

I am wondering how to multiply through a numpy array, step by step. The cumsum function is incorrect for what I really want to do. I suppose a for loop could work?

For example if I had the following array

```
data = [1.01, 1.02, 1.08, 0.99, 0.98, 1.02]
```

and I want to multiply through this array by 10,000 but in a cumulative fashion... such as:

```
[10100, 10302, 11126.16, 11014.89, 10794.60, 11010.49]
```

10,000 * data[0], then that result * data[1], then that result * data[2]..and so on

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIUC, you want [`cumprod`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html):

```
>>> data = np.array([1.01, 1.02, 1.08, 0.99, 0.98, 1.02])
>>> data.cumprod() * 10000
array([ 10100.        ,  10302.        ,  11126.16      ,  11014.8984    ,
        10794.600432  ,  11010.49244064])
```

Comment: thanks DSM - that is quite useful! I found an online list for these types of functions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop:

```
result = 10000
for i in xrange(len(array)):
    array[i] *= result
    result = array[i]
```

Comment: Outlaw Lemur - thank you for the 'for loop'. although the answer from DSM is probably easier to manipulate, yours works as well and is quite useful. I have added it to my database.. appreciate your input!

Comment: @antonio_zeus No problem! I mostly used this because it works with/out  numpy and in other languages too:)